# d3.svg.line() error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the following code to try to draw a path using d3.js
I have tried various code examples on the web about the same and have been getting the same error everywhere.

Following is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var svg;
    //The data for our line
 lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                 { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                 { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

//This is the accessor function we talked about above
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                         .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                         .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
                                    .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                            .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                            .attr("stroke", "blue")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                            .attr("fill", "none");
    </script>
```

The error is: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined**

This comes at the following line: `var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()`

I am not sure what 'undefined' means here. Any leads?

Comment: `d3.svg` is undefined? maybe d3 is not loaded.

Comment: @Fabricator I have loaded the script in the head by the following: <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.44.min.js"></script>

Comment: you forgot the protocol, it should be `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.44.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Fabricator is right, this works under a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ky389sbp/

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Reading your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619798/d3-svg-line-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-line-of-undefine#comment62722237_37619798) I suppose you are using D3 **v4**. As of [version 4](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#shapes-d3-shape) there is no `d3.svg`, hence the error message. The line generator you are looking for is now defined as [`d3.line()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#line).

If you were still using version 3, it would be `d3.svg.line()` instead.

---

Also, as other answerers have noted, this will lead to a follow-up error when leaving the rest of the statement untouched as `d3.line` does not feature a method `.interpolate()`. D3 v4 has [*curve factories*](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curves) for this purpose, which are used for interpolation. These factories are supplied to the line generator using [`line.curve()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#line_curve). D3 v3's `.interpolate("linear")` now becomes `.curve(d3.curveLinear)`. However, since `line.curve()` defaults to `d3.curveLinear` this can safely be omitted in your case.

The statement thus becomes:

```
var lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
  .curve(d3.curveLinear);          // Use for clarity, omit for brevity.
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your code has modified in the below syntax since there is no ***d3.svg*** in version 4.

```
var lineFunction = d3.line()
                     .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                     .y(function(d) { return d.y; });
```

Answer (score 3):

[Update]

Also, if you are using D3js v4, a problem with this statement `.interpolate("linear");` will occur with this warning:

`d3.line(...).x(...).y(...).interpolate is not a function`.

In this new version, `.interpolate("linear");` should be changed to:

`curve(d3.curveLinear);`

As in the description of [curveLinear](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveLinear).