# Creating line chart with d3 getting error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, graphics

In the following example I am using a lineFunction for plotting co-ordinates for the path. I hope to enter code correctly, still facing error. Can someone help?

**SNIPPET:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){

    //our basic data 
     var customData = [
        {"x": 100, "y": 100},
        {"x": 200, "y": 50},
        {"x": 300, "y": 150},
        {"x": 400, "y": 20}
     ];

    //the line function for path 
    var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
        .interpolate("linear");

    //Main svg container
    var mySVG = d3.select("svg");

    //defining the lines
    var path = mySVG.append("path");

    //plotting lines
    path
        .attr("d", lineFunction(customData))
        .attr("stroke",function() { return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)"; })
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
});
</script>   
</head>

<body>
    <svg width="500px" height="500px"></svg> 
</body>
</html>
```

**ERROR:**

[image]

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line() //error here ...
```

Comment: looks like versioning issue for me

Comment: Are you included your libraries above your script? You probably are but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like versioning issue for me take look at this -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    //our basic data 
     var customData = [
        {"x": 100, "y": 100},
        {"x": 200, "y": 50},
        {"x": 300, "y": 150},
        {"x": 400, "y": 20}
     ];

    //the line function for path 
    var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
        .interpolate("linear");

    //Main svg container
    var mySVG = d3.select("svg");

    //defining the lines
    var path = mySVG.append("path");

    //plotting lines
    path
        .attr("d", lineFunction(customData))
        .attr("stroke",function() { return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)"; })
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script></script>
  <svg width="500px" height="500px"></svg>
```

Comment: help out with new version. Though I agree with old version its running ...

Answer (score 1):

As Chetan already mentioned, it's a version problem of your included D3 file. You are including D3 V4 but using the syntax of D3 V3.

Within V4 they removed d3.svg. So everything you have to do is to change d3.svg.line() to d3.line() and it should work.

Ref: [d3.svg.line() error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619798/d3-svg-line-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-line-of-undefine)

EDIT-1: try this code Snippet

```
var svg;
//The data for our line
var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
    { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
    { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

//This is the accessor function we talked about above
var lineFunction = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
```

Comment: index.html:25 Uncaught TypeError: d3.line(...).x(...).y(...).interpolate is not a function(…) <------- This is the error I am getting now, after making d3.line() change.

Comment: Because .interpolate is also no longer part of d3.line() in V4. Have a look at the Reference I linked and the API of D3 V4 :)