# Draw SVG path using object / array of points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

For whatever reason, [the example in this link here](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js) is not working for me, which is frustrating.

[I have a codepen here](https://codepen.io/canovice/pen/vjYoEx?editors=0010) where I am trying to draw an MLB stadium as an SVG, however i am struggling to create a path object using the code from the link above. What isn't working is the following:

```
 //The data for our line
 var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                  { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                  { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

 //This is the accessor function we talked about above
 var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                          .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                          .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                            .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                            .attr("stroke", "blue")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                            .attr("fill", "none");
```

The code in my codepen is modified slightly to append to the svg I have already created, rather than the one initialized in the example. I'm getting a seemingly obvious error *Cannot read property 'line' of undefined* but I'm not sure why I'm getting this. I have d3 included in codepen.

Any help here is appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: Looks like I need to be using d3.line(), still working on getting it to work

Comment: [This thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619798/d3-svg-line-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-line-of-undefine) appears to answer my question...